# Is a string comparison or a hash lookup faster in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I have some code that at one part will get executed a lot, and I'm wondering which implementation will run faster. I will use a for loop to simulate the part the gets executed a lot:

option A:

```
my %sections = (
    'somestring1' => 1,
    'somestring2' => 1,
    'somestring3' => 1,
    'somestring4' => 1
);

for (0..10000)
{
    # $element is chosen at random
    $namespace = $element if $sections{$element};
}
```

option B:

```
for (0..10000)
{
    # $element is chosen at random
    $namespace = $element if ($element eq'somestring1' || 
                            $element eq'somestring2' ||
                            $element eq'somestring3' ||
                            $element eq'somestring4');
}
```

Can anyone benchmark this or know the answer as I am not familiar with benchmarking tools.

This code probably doesn't make sense in this context but it is in fact what I need to use.

Comment: First make it run, then make it fast.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `cmpthese` function from the [Benchmark](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark) module

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw'cmpthese';

my %sections = (
    somestring1 => 1,
    somestring2 => 1,
    somestring3 => 1,
    somestring4 => 1
);

my @elements = map { 'somestring' . int(1 + rand(10)) } 1 .. 100;

my $namespace;

cmpthese(100000, {
    hash_value => sub {
        foreach my $element (@elements) {
            $namespace = $element if $sections{$element};
        }
    },
    hash_exists => sub {
        foreach my $element (@elements) {
            $namespace = $element if exists $sections{$element};
        }
    },
    string_cmp => sub {
        foreach my $element (@elements) {
            $namespace = $element if (
                $element eq'somestring1' ||
                $element eq'somestring2' ||
                $element eq'somestring3' ||
                $element eq'somestring4');
        }
    },
});
```

My results (running Perl 5.10 on WinXP):

```
               Rate  string_cmp  hash_value hash_exists
string_cmp  18932/s          --        -44%        -50%
hash_value  33512/s         77%          --        -12%
hash_exists 38095/s        101%         14%          --
```

So a hash lookup is 77% faster than the cascaded string comparisons and checking for hash existence instead of value (as Adam Bellaire suggested) is 14% faster still.

Comment: I have a bad feeling, but I'd be interested to see how testing against the regex `/^somestring[1234]$/` would compare to those three methods. I expect it not to be as fast as `exists` but I'd like to see how it stacks up against the string comparison.

Comment: I show `/^somestring[1234]$/` as about 3% slower than the string comparisons, though real-world performance would depend heavily on the number of keys and the pattern (if any) in their values.

Comment: The results are a bit aged. I ran out of space writing an update here, so I will make a new answer post.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that the first version, with `exists` is going to be faster, not to mention more readable and maintainable.

```
for (0..10000)
{
    # $element is chosen at random
    $namespace = $element if exists $sections{$element};
}
```

Merely checking for the existence of a hash key is quicker than retrieving its value for comparison, so use `exists`.

Answer (score 4):

The hash lookup mechanism is considerably faster.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the time to get familiar with benchmarking tools, like the CPAN module [Benchmark](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark).

Comment: This is true, however if the hash becomes very large, I can't imagine advocating inlining the values into a giant boolean expression for performance reasons.

Comment: You're right, which means I misunderstood the question.. I thought the OP was wanting to check if the key was in a *subset* of all keys in the hash, rather than in the hash itself. Fixing response. :)

Answer (score 2):

Michael Carman's benchmark is nice, but the results are quite aged by now, so people not running it on their own machine might get the wrong idea.
So, the exact same benchmark (just 10x more cases to give more consistent results) on a Mac Pro w/ Mac OS X and Perl 5.24.1:

```
               Rate  string_cmp hash_exists  hash_value
string_cmp  54142/s          --        -28%        -32%
hash_exists 74850/s         38%          --         -7%
hash_value  80192/s         48%          7%          --
```

However, on an AWS with CentOS 7 / Perl 5.24.0 we get:

```
string_cmp  70373/s          --        -24%        -25%
hash_value  92851/s         32%          --         -1%
hash_exists 93545/s         33%          1%          --
```

So, I would say test your own machine, but exists doesn't seem to offer a benefit currently (on my Mac with latest Perl it is even measurably slower in this specific test - and about even on other tests).

One thing I don't like about the benchmark is that it rather arbitrarily chooses to compare 4 equalities with a hash check. Don't be confused, if we only have one item in the hash, so we compare with a single equality we get (on my Mac Pro / Perl 5.24.1):

```
hash_value  119474/s          --         -1%        -14%        -34%
hash_exists 121065/s          1%          --        -12%        -33%
grep        138122/s         16%         14%          --        -23%
string_cmp  180180/s         51%         49%         30%          --
```

I threw in there a single grep that avoids the foreach loop for comparison. So, a single equality is obviously faster than a hash check, but not twice as fast so if you can replace just two equalities with a hash check you get a benefit:

```
string_cmp  104167/s          --        -15%        -17%
hash_value  121951/s         17%          --         -2%
hash_exists 125000/s         20%          2%          --
```

However, this is with the hash pre-built outside the loop like in the original example. What if we create the hash on each benchmark cycle? I.e. you have a couple of values you want to check for existence in an array, is the overhead of creating a hash with them worth it? I won't bore you with more results since you might find they are different on your machine, but the answer is that for 2 values "it depends" (so perhaps you shouldn't bother), but for 3 or more you should do it.